# Why cannot Restart-Computer with task scheduler?

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I am using Windows 10 now. I have these scripts in my C:\Users\luke\Documents\04_Stop_local.ps1:

```
Send-MailMessage -To "luke@myluke.com" -From "luke@myluke.com" -Subject "Rebooting your laptop" -SmtpServer "smtp.myluke.com"
Restart-Computer -computerName lukeX1 -force
```

I can reboot my laptop named lukeX1 when I run these scripts in my PowerShell ISE, PowerShell command window, and can run it in windows command:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -ExecutionPolicy Bypass C:\Users\luke\Documents\04_Stop_local.ps1
```

But when I try to schedule it in my task scheduler. Just send me the notice email (1st step). The laptop didn't restart...

Why? I used the same login(user).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you give it "Run with highest permissions"?

Comment: add logging to your script to see the errors.  Perhaps Start-Transcript is handy here.

Comment: `try
{
    Restart-Computer -computerName lukeX1 -force
    "Executed" | Out-File C:\Logfile.txt
}
catch
{
    $msg = $_.Exception.Message
    $msg | Out-File C:\LogFile.txt
}`